# EF Core difference between ToListAsync() and FromSqlRaw().ToListAsync()

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework Core 6. Basically the latest version to date and I'm seeing a significant difference in performance for these 2 blocks of code:

```
var items = await context.Items.Where(...).ToListAsync();
```

And:

```
var sql = context.Items.Where(...).ToQueryString();
var items = await context.Items.FromSqlRaw(sql).ToListAsync();
```

As a user I'd imagine the first block of code converts into the second one inside the library but apparently something else happens behind the scene. The resulting query has to be the same as all the conditions and everything is identical. Yet block #1 fails with the timeout and block #2 executes super fast and I get results immediately.

What's going on?

---

**UPDATE 1.**

My `.Where(...)` clause looks like this:

```
.Where(ro => ro.AccountId == accountId &&
(
    ro.CustomerEmail == query.Email ||
    ro.CustomerEmail1 == query.Email ||
    ro.CustomerEmail2 == query.Email
))
```

---

**UPDATE 2.**

This is the SQL that I get from `ToQueryString()` call (I formatted it for readability):

```
DECLARE @__account_AccountId_0 nvarchar(200) = N'12345678';
DECLARE @__email_1 nvarchar(200) = N'test@gmail.com';

SELECT [r].* -- all fields
FROM [MyTable] AS [r]
WHERE ([r].[AccountId] = @__account_AccountId_0) AND (
    (([r].[CustomerEmail] = @__email_1) OR 
    ([r].[CustomerEmail1] = @__email_1)) OR 
    ([r].[CustomerEmail2] = @__email_1))
```

Comment: What does your SQL look like? Did you track on your database, what SQL is actually executed in both cases?

Comment: @nvoigt the query is very simple. The database though is pretty large and has a bunch of indexes. Yet both resulting sql queries have to be the same right? I don't have any interceptors within the context or triggers in the database - nothing should affect the execution of the query.

Comment: But have you confirmed it? There may be some extra optimisations that EF can perform in the first case or it may be more work for EF in the second case. Starting by checking (not assuming) the actual queries being performed is a good start.

Comment: I don't know, I guess they aren't. Since we cannot debug your program or check your database, you have to tell us I'm afraid...

Comment: @nvoigt just added my `Where(...)` code

Comment: `ToQueryString()` is for debug purposes only. In most of the cases, it is **not** the exact SQL which will be executed by LINQ query. Especially the parameters part.

Comment: So do you have access to your database and can you see what SQL is *actually* executed? Next best thing might be to add a logger to your EF context.

Comment: @nvoigt just added another update. The sql that I get from ToQueryString call. It kinda looks to me that the number of brackets is not correct around the email conditions...

Comment: But you're still proceeding on the *assumption* that the SQL is the same. If you're using SQL Server, for instance, you should run SQL Server *profiler* and observe the *actual SQL* sent by the first query.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Right. I'll check that for sure. Need some time

Comment: I do not know if that's actually the case, but I have one theory, which i hope someone can either confirm or dismiss. If Items has **owned** relations, `ToList` methods  familly probably appends all owned related data -thus taking more time- while the debuging nature of `ToQueryString` does not take relations into account. If that's what happening on your case, unless the cascading `ToListAsync` does not take care of that, all owned related data should be missing, tho.